# Unexpected results when adding tensorflow batches

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, training-data

I added code to read my csv file in batches and I notices it influenced the loss in a bad way I think. The results are like this

Loss over 3000 epochs
[image]
And for an bit more visual overview
[image]

So scenario 1 is that I read in my csv, shuffle the full array and then take batches of 150 each and go through the file 3000 times

In scenario 2 I do not read the full file but use the method proposed on the tensorflow website. I prefer this method because I don't have to read large csv files into my memory. The code I have is like this:

```
def input_pipeline(file, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([file], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
  example, label = read_from_csv(filename_queue)
  min_after_dequeue = 1000
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
  return example_batch, label_batch
```

The number of epochs and the batchsize is the same.
**Why are the results so different when using the same configuration except the way the data is read from the file?**

**EDIT**
One other thing. The tensorflow batch method is about 7 minutes slower(at least when I use a small csv). Is this normal?

Comment: Is it possible that the CSV is not random? Don't assume that `shuffle_batch` will take care of it. It can only shuffle the ones waiting in the queue. You can try to rise `min_after_dequeue` to see if it improves.

Comment: @ManoloSantos the csv is not random. I have a csv of `31000` lines of ~ 300 lines per output and these are ordered by label. So using the `shuffle_batch` I would train one person in 2 epochs and not a little bit of everyone so I understand why for this file the `shuffle_batch` doesn't work. But I also have a small csv file with 22 samples and that should fit perfectly fine in the queue.The results in the question are of this small csv file. If I understand correctly each batch would contain `150 / 22 = 6.81` epochs of data. So each batch contains data from each person. SoWhatMakesTheDifference

Comment: @ManoloSantos do you have another clue/hint?